# LinkedHashSet Equals Method

Tags: java, hashset, linkedhashset

I have a two sets of `LinkedHashSet` objects, within this objects I have other objects that have more `LinkedHashSet`.

**My question is:**

Does the `equals` method (default) checks if all the inside `HashSets` are the same? Or do I have to overwrite it?

Comment: Aside from the Docs explaining this, why not write a simple test case and find out?

Answer (score 8):

By default it will make sure the contents of the HashSets are equals().  LinkedHashSet is also ordered, but this is not used in hashCode or equals so they could have different orders and still be equals = true.

In short, the order doesn't matter for equals of HashSets, and "equals" is not "same".  "same" usually means its the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The contract for `Set.equals()` is that every member of each set is contained in the other. Each `contains` test relies on the `equals()` method of the objects in the sets.

This specification requires that no `Set` implementation can rely on the default implementation of `equals()`, which is object identity. (As far as the `Set` specification goes, the objects in the set are free to use the default `Object.equals()` to test equality. But if you have a set of sets, the objects in the (outer) set are themselves `Set` objects, and thus subject to the same `Set` contract regarding `equals()`.)

For more info, see the docs for [`Set.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`Set.contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).